# CSS hover suddenly works on mobile browsers?

Tags: css, mobile, browser, hover

This is really odd. I'm not complaining that something works, but it is very surprising .. 
On my website I had the usual css :hover for the navigation to reveal sublinks. But on the mobile browsers this needed some js help to make it work (as you can see from those many posts about "css hover not working on mobile browsers")
I made a simple script to fix the hover problem. But today as I was rewriting the code, since I noticed that it was not fully working as intended, I removed the entire mobileDetect.js which was handling the mobile hover. And now it works, without any additional scripts. 
I tested it with chrome and safari on my ipad and iphone. It works as intended... did I misse out a big mobile browser update or something?

I use Jquery from google, no framework and standard HTML5.
Here is the site : (easy-sailing.ch) "EVENTS" and "AUSBILDUNG" are the mentioned navigations with sublinks.

I am just wondering if this is some odd anomaly and therefor should put my script back in or just enjoy the good news? :S

Comment: How does hovering behave when there's no on-screen cursor?

Comment: It could be that your phone is just loading a cached version of the site. Remove the site data and try and connect to it again, or use someone else's and test from there.

Comment: @MattBall There is an onscreen cursor for certain phones, http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_3-5665.php.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i remember it has always been working...

...it is just not needed because there's no cursor and hover happens usually when you click (touch in this case) and you'll leave the page before noticing hover.

on android i can observe it when i touch+slide up or down.

Comment: That's exactly what was happening before and why I had to write a script which made the first touch reveal sublinks and the second allow link. 
But now(I deleted all cookies and muffins ;) and it still works as intended: first touch = hover(reveal content) second click allow link....

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this for me by removing :hover selectors/rules at runtime https://github.com/kof/remove-hover